# US to Metric: Convert Sum or Convert Individually?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, precision

I am working on a program which will allow users to enter a measurement in either metric or US units and store it in a database.

Later, the user should be allowed to retrieve the sum of multiple measurements and display in in either unit.

My question is which practice would be considered best?

1. In the database, record the measurements the user entered and the unit they entered each as. Upon retrieval, sum the entries for both units and convert the undesired unit before adding both together.
2. Only store a single unit of measurement in the database. Convert each entry by the user into the desired unit before storing. Upon request, retrieve the sum of all values and either convert or display as is.

Mathematically I realize that since conversion simply involves multiplication, and that:

```
ax + ay + az = a(x + y + z)
```

it shouldn't make a difference, but, well, there's a reason it's called Computer *Science* and not Computer *Math*. I can't help but feel like method 2 introduces a lot more points for the floating point math to go wrong. Am I just being paranoid from years of Python programming?

Further Information:

- The maximum decimal accuracy allowed to be entered is 4
- The database is storing the values as Decimal(20,6)
- SQL Server 2008
- The page for data entry will likely be ASP.Net with C# code-behind

Comment: Seems like the worst case scenario is you'd lose a small amount of precision if you convert each item then add versus add then convert, but unless you're adding thousands of items it might not make a practical difference. It would, though, be a valid argument to aggregate first, then convert.

Comment: @DStanley Makes sense. Truth is that usage is an unknown factor in all this. It's a new feature, and we only have a vague idea how often people will be entering new data.

Comment: Aside: When I was working on a control system for a seamless pipe mill I wanted to confirm that coating weight was really in grams per square foot. They explained that they take a roll of aluminum foil one foot wide and cut off a one foot length, then tape it to the mandrel before running it through the graphite coating box. Afterwards, they peel it off and put it on their laboratory balance. Hence, grams per square foot. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend storing the measurements individually, in SI. If you store them in the origin unit system, you need more data to canonically represent each measurement. This is because other unit systems have more than one choice for the unit of a particular quantity. So if not in SI, a volume might be in cubic feet, cubic inches, pints, quarts, gallons, barrels, acre-feet, barn-megaparsecs or fluid ounces (whereas in SI there is only one choice).

You should also be aware that "what you are measuring" and "the units it's expressed in" are completely different concepts - one is semantic, the other is syntax.

Don't lose the semantics of the measurement - if, for example, you're measuring liquid volume, store that fact alongside the value you're storing. Otherwise you can get issues converting between unit systems (for example, in SI all volumes are in m^3, but in US imperial units, a gas volume would typically be in a different unit from a liquid volume), and you lose the ability to tell if it makes sense to add them etc...

Of course, if you're certain that only the sum is ever going to be of significance, you should store just the sum, simply because the individual data points will take far more space. But I would still recommend SI for the storage.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on semantics vs syntax. The sum is the only significant value, but the user needs to be able to go back and edit individual values if needed (e.g they made a mistake), so each has to be stored as a row.

Answer (score 2):

For such projects, we should adopt an approach for separation of concerns. I'd suggest storing only unitary measurements in the database. Database is after all nothing but a storehouse of data and nothing more.

You should let the application perform the business logic. I'd suggest using a Factory to generate measurements for each unit.

Plain and simple, the database should store only data and the Application only should perform the business logic.

Comment: 100% agree.  Make a decision to store them in Metric, then use a conversion on the business layer.  The same way I'd recommend storing date/times in UTC if dealing with multiple time zones and update the business side to display/update if needed.